# Anaconda cannot update a Python package

Tags: python, anaconda

My python program will not run, and I'm told it may be because of an old version of hyperopt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hyperas_my_data.py", line 74, in <module>
    ...
  File "/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hyperopt-0.0.4-py2.7.egg/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 306, in fmin
  File "/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hyperopt-0.0.4-py2.7.egg/hyperopt/base.py", line 633, in fmin
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

The version of hyperopt being used by my Python program is 0.0.4; however, according to anaconda, the installed version is actually 0.0.3.dev:

```
user@GPU6:~/dir$ python
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import hyperopt
>>> hyperopt.__version__
'0.0.3.dev'
```

I tried to update hyperopt, but the output said that hyperopt was already installed and up to date. I found that hyperopt is actually on version 0.1, so I thought I'd try to install that specifically:

```
user@GPU6:~/dir$ conda install hyperopt=0.1
Fetching package metadata .........

PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - hyperopt 0.1*
```

I'm working inside `screen` to be able to use Anaconda. 
How can I update hyperopt?

**Update**

I found [these instructions][1] and tried it out:

```
user@GPU6:~/dir$ conda install -c jaikumarm hyperopt=0.1
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    future:   0.16.0-py27_1        

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    hyperopt: 0.0.4-py27_0  creditx --> 0.1-0 jaikumarm

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

user@GPU6:~/dir$ python
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import hyperopt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named hyperopt
>>> exit()
```

So now I don't even have my old version of hyperas. Any ideas on how to install version 0.1?

**Update 2**

I uninstalled hyperopt using `conda remove hyperopt` and re-ran `conda install -c jaikumarm hyperopt=0.1`. I still cannot import hyperopt, but it is listed under my installed packages:

```
`user@GPU6:~/dir$ conda list
# packages in environment at /mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2:
...
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py27_1
hyperopt                  0.1                           0    jaikumarm
idna                      2.1                      py27_0
...
```

Update 3: in response to a comment, here is my PYTHONPATH and my OS.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-111-generic x86_64)

```
user@GPU6:~$ which python
/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/bin/python

user@GPU6:~$ python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)"

/export/mlrg/user
/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip
/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7
/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg
/mnt/data/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg
```

**Update 3**

Interestingly, I can use hyperopt version 0.1 when I'm outside `screen`, where I have a different Python installation, even though I only installed it when I was inside a `screen`. For example:

```
user@GPU6:~/dir$ which python
/mnt/data/user/pkgs/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/bin/python
user@GPU6:~/dir$ python
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 | 64-bit | (default, Sep 15 2014, 17:36:10) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hyperopt
>>> hyperopt.__version__
'0.1'
```

But I need to use the Anaconda version. Once I enter a screen session, I'm using Anaconda, and I need to use hyperopt version 0.1. How can I get Anaconda to recognize that hyperopt is installed? Something to do with my $PYTHONPATH?

```
  [1]: https://anaconda.org/jaikumarm/hyperopt
```

Comment: What OS is this, and what is the value of your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Hi @darthbith, please see my update.

Comment: Although it doesn't say it, that version of hyperopt from that channel only has a Python 3.5 package. You're probably better off installing this using the instructions in the documentation for hyperopt

Comment: Hmm..I can't seem to do that anymore. I seem to be stuck downloading 0.1. Do you have a specific command I can use? For example, I tried `conda install hyperopt=0.0.4` (because I had 0.0.4 before I tried updating) but I get `PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current linux-64 channels: - hyperopt 0.0.4*`

Comment: Sorry, never mind, this worked: `conda install -c creditx hyperopt=0.0.4`

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about that @darthbith, because I can import hyperopt in Canopy for Python 2.7.6 (yes, old!):
`user@GPU6:~/dir$ python
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 | 64-bit | (default, Sep 15 2014, 17:36:10) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hyperopt`
>>> hyperopt.__version__
'0.1'

Comment: If you download the tarball and unzip it, you will see that the directory layout is for Python 3.5. Not sure why it would work in Canopy but not elsewhere.